# How to reshape a dataframe and extend the number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make this kind of transformations :

[image]

I tried so many reshape functions but still not getting the expected output.

Do you have any ideas, please ?  If needed, here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ID_X', 'A01', 'Green', 'A02', 'Cerise', 'ID_Y', 'A01', 'Azure', 'A02', 'Black'],
                   'B': ['ID_X', 'B01', 'Red', 'B02', 'Celeste', 'ID_Y', 'B01', 'Beige', 'B02', 'Rose'],
                   'C': ['ID_X', 'C01', 'Brown', 'C02', 'Orange', 'ID_Y', 'C01', 'Canary', 'C02', 'White'],
                   'TYPE': ['ID', 'POSITION', 'COLOR', 'POSITION', 'COLOR', 'ID', 'POSITION', 'COLOR',
                            'POSITION', 'COLOR']})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Cumcount to mark your different groups
df['column'] = df[df.TYPE.eq('ID')].groupby('TYPE').cumcount()
df.column = df.column.ffill()

# pivot_table, transpose, explode different levels, and reset the index:
out = (df.pivot_table(index='TYPE', columns='column', aggfunc=list)
         .T
         .explode('ID')
         .explode(['COLOR', 'POSITION'])
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
TYPE    COLOR    ID POSITION
0       Green  ID_X      A01
1      Cerise  ID_X      A02
2       Azure  ID_Y      A01
3       Black  ID_Y      A02
4         Red  ID_X      B01
5     Celeste  ID_X      B02
6       Beige  ID_Y      B01
7        Rose  ID_Y      B02
8       Brown  ID_X      C01
9      Orange  ID_X      C02
10     Canary  ID_Y      C01
11      White  ID_Y      C02
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by following the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'A': ['ID_X', 'A01', 'Green', 'ID_Y', 'A01', 'Yellow'],
 'B': ['ID_X', 'B01', 'Red', 'ID_Y', 'B01', 'Blue'],
 'C': ['ID_X', 'C01', 'Brown', 'ID_Y', 'C01', 'Purple'],
 'TYPE': ['ID', 'POSITION', 'COLOR', 'ID', 'POSITION', 'COLOR']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.TYPE.unique())
for i in range (0, df.shape[0]-1, 3):
    temp = df.iloc[i:i+3,:-1].T
    temp.columns = df1.columns
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,temp])
```

Comment: expensive when you use concat multiple times; if you can, get the list of dataframes and call concat once

Answer (score 1):

One option is to transpose the columns, flatten it, and then reshape with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

temp = (df
        .assign(ID = df.C.where(df.TYPE.eq('ID'), np.nan).ffill())
        .loc[lambda df: df.C.ne(df.ID)]
        .set_index(['ID','TYPE'])
        .T)

temp.columns = temp.columns.map('|'.join)

(temp
.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('ID', '.value'), 
    names_sep='|')
)

      ID POSITION    COLOR
0   ID_X      A01    Green
1   ID_X      B01      Red
2   ID_X      C01    Brown
3   ID_X      A02   Cerise
4   ID_X      B02  Celeste
5   ID_X      C02   Orange
6   ID_Y      A01    Azure
7   ID_Y      B01    Beige
8   ID_Y      C01   Canary
9   ID_Y      A02    Black
10  ID_Y      B02     Rose
11  ID_Y      C02    White
```

Comment: You made it look so simple! I will try to understand how janitor made it in this one. Thank you so much sammywemmy.

Comment: Sure, have a look at the [docs](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) and also this [blog post](https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling-blog/python/pandas/reshape/wide-to-long/pivot_longer/stack/2022/09/08/Pivot_longer-Reshape-Data-in-Pandas-with-Ease-From-Wide-to-Long.html) for guide on its usage.

Answer (score 1):

Using reshaping with index deduplication and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
out = (df
 .assign(n=df['TYPE'].eq('ID').cumsum(),
         n2=lambda d: d.groupby(['TYPE', 'n']).cumcount())
 .set_index(['TYPE', 'n', 'n2'])
 .stack().unstack('TYPE')
 .groupby(level=['n', -1]).ffill()
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
      COLOR    ID POSITION
0     Green  ID_X      A01
1       Red  ID_X      B01
2     Brown  ID_X      C01
3    Cerise  ID_X      A02
4   Celeste  ID_X      B02
5    Orange  ID_X      C02
6     Azure  ID_Y      A01
7     Beige  ID_Y      B01
8    Canary  ID_Y      C01
9     Black  ID_Y      A02
10     Rose  ID_Y      B02
11    White  ID_Y      C02
```

Comment: So many good memories! I used to create colorful visualizations for my I/O to make the expected reshaping as clear as possible. It's been a year and I can't believe I'll be awarded the golden pandas badge in maybe just a few hours. And to be honest, that's mainly thanks to you ;)

Comment: Hehe I stumbled upon this and thought I'd answer it :p

Comment: Happy soon-to-come gold badge, it's well deserved.